# Displaying imported date with data

Tags: matlab, date, xlsread

I need to display an imported date on the legend for a figure, I'm importing a number of different values that correspond to different dates. However the legend just displays 'Data1', 'Data2' etc. I'm not sure how to go about having the date matched up to the value imported.

```
[num,text] = xlsread(gT);
t = [100:50:200]';
d = num(t,:)/256;d = d';
D = linspace(0, 13.5, 39); D = D';
plot(d,D)
set(gca,'Ydir','reverse');
legend('show')
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I managed to figure it out, was surprisingly easy.

```
    [num,text] = xlsread(gT);
    t = [100:80:400]';
    d = num(t,:)/256;d = d';
    D = linspace(0, 13.5, 39); D = D';
    figure(2);
    plot(d,D)
    set(gca,'Ydir','reverse');
    legend(strcat(text(t)))
```